# How do I prevent React list component from refreshing when props update?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a list component that uses a prop to amend the subscription parameters for the purpose of limiting displayed results. This works ok, however I would like to prevent the table from entirely refreshing when I add an extra 5 results to the list. Is this possible? Currently I update the props via a method I pass down from the parent component. I've included this at the bottom of the code.

Any advice appreciated!

```
export default class ListingTable extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {
  static propTypes = {
    LimitProp: React.PropTypes.number,
  }
  static defaultProps = {
    LimitProp: 5
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const subscription =  Meteor.subscribe("allLists",{sort: {_id:-1}, limit: this.props.LimitProp})
    this.state = {
      listData: subscription,
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.LimitProp != nextProps.LimitProp) {
      // Stop old subscription
      this.state.eventsData.stop()
      // Setup new subscription
      const subscription = Meteor.subscribe("allLists",{sort: {_id:-1}, limit:       nextProps.LimitProp})
      this.setState({ listData: subscription })
    }
  }


  ...
  render() {
  ...
    <a className="item" onClick= {(event) => this.props.methodLoadMore(event)}>Load More</a>
    ...

  }

//this method is in the parent component, onClick Method calls this
loadMore(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation
  event.preventDefault()

  var limit = this.state.listLimit;
  limit = limit + 5
  this.setState({listLimit: limit})
  FlowRouter.setQueryParams({limit: limit})
}
```

Comment: look into the reacte lifecycle method `shouldComponenentUpdate`

Comment: My understanding is that if I use shouldComponentUpdate to prevent the component from re-rendering, then the list won't be extended at all. What i'm looking for is the list to re-render without it completely refreshing. So that 5 additional items just append to the list. Hope that makes sense?..

Comment: did you get a solution to this?